# How to store boolean value against radio button

Tags: radio-button

In my visualforce page I have two command button. I want to store boolean value into database against those radio button. I have chosen the field type as 'checkbox'. Please help me.

**My vf code is**

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" controller="RadioButtonTestController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:form >
    <div align="center">

        <apex:selectRadio value="{!Country}" > 
           India <apex:selectOption itemValue="true"></apex:selectOption>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          China &nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:selectOption itemValue="false"></apex:selectOption>

            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" 
                    action="{!checkSelectedValue}" 
                    reRender="none"/>
            </apex:selectRadio>

        <apex:commandButton value="Show country" action="{!showCountry}"/>
    </div>
</apex:form>
```

My Controller is: `

```
public class RadioButtonTestController
```

{
    public Boolean Country{get; set;}
    public void checkSelectedValue()
    {

```
    system.debug('Selected value is: '+ Country);
}

public void showCountry()
{
    String caseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CaseID');
    list<Storing_Location__c> str = [Select Country__c from Storing_Location__c where CaseNumID__c=: caseId];
    Storing_Location__c obj = new Storing_Location__c();
    if(str.size()>0)
    {
        obj.Id = str[0].Id;
    }

    obj.Country__c = Country;
    system.debug('Selected value is:***********************:::'+Country);

}
```

}

Comment: where is your controller? how are you planning to do this, what exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I used radio button before and stored values in string. But in this case how can I store boolean values? And to do that what is the field type?

Comment: What you are planning to do with radio button

Comment: My requirement is to store Boolean value for those two radio button in Country__c which is a checkbox type field.

Comment: When you say "I have chosen the field type as 'checkbox'", what is the field and object you mean?  Is it the Country__c field in Storing_Location__c object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution myself

**The controller should be:**

[image]

Here the database field **"Country__c"** is checkbox type. So it takes only Boolean value. If User select **"India"** then field **"Country__c"** will be checked otherwise not.